Probability and fairness when rectifying a misplayed roll of dice.
I have a quick probability question that came up during a boardgame recently.  The rules and situation can be generalized to the following.
A person rolls 2 dice.  If they are unhappy with the results for whatever reason they may reroll one or both a single time, and must keep the results. However they may not reroll any dice that show the number five.
A person rolls and gets a 5 and any other number.  They decide that they want to reroll, but mistakenly grab both dice and reroll, which is disallowed. They should have only rerolled one die. Their mistaken reroll however results in a 5 and another number.
The question is, are the following two options equally fair?

Ignore the 5 (because it was the same as the original 5 they should not have rolled) and accept the result of the other die
Discard the results, set one die back to 5 and reroll the other by itself

If the person had rolled any number other than 5 they would have been forced into option 2, because it clearly would be unfair to allow them to choose from two die results when they were only allowed roll one.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The rules of the game are not clear:  what's the goal?  If the goal is to get as many $5's$ as possible, then I see no problem if my opponent chooses to re-roll a $5$.  That's a bad move for them as, at best, they can only break even.  But if they want to do it, it's fine with me.  Of course, the goal might be different.  Without knowing more, issues of "fairness" don't appear to make sense.

Edited for clarity

To phrase the question in mathematical terms, suppose you roll two dice. Given that at least one of the dice shows a 5, what is the distribution of the other number? In particular, is it equal to the distribution of a single fair dice roll?
Enumerating the equiprobable outcomes where at least one of the dice rolls a 5, there are 11 outcomes. In two of them the other number is a 1, so the conditional probability of getting a 1 is $\frac2{11}$. The same can be said of the conditional probability of getting the numbers 2, 3, 4, and 6. However there is only one outcome where both dice roll a 5, so the conditional probability of this is $\frac1{11}$. So the conditional distribution is not equal to the distribution of a single fair dice roll; you have a relatively lower chance of getting a 5.

I have adjusted my question for clarity above.
